# Show component with changed property in design (not default)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, custom-component

I have a little problem with my component. This looks like my property:

```
private ViewType _viewType = ViewType.Week;
        public ViewType DisplayType
        {
            get { return _viewType; }
            set
            {
                _viewType = value;
                if (panelKalendar != null)
                    panelKalendar.Invalidate();
            }
        }
```

and this I have in Kalendar_Load():

```
...
if (this._viewType == ViewType.Month)
                panelKalendar.Top = yPoloha;
            else if (this._viewType == ViewType.Week)
                panelKalendar.Top = yPoloha + VYSKA_BUNKY;
...
```

(class ViewType)

```
public enum ViewType
        {
            Week,
            Month,
        }
```

when I add my component to app It looks fine. I have default week, my component is in design draw with week looks. But when I change it to Month, in Design it is shown bad, it gets the second if in kalendar_load (`panelKalendar.Top = yPoloha + VYSKA_BUNKY`). When I built it, it´s ok. And that´s problem. Why Designer use default property and not that which is set? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load is not called when a component is in the designer.  Code in properties and in the constructor are.  If you want changing the viewType property to cause a change in the designer you will need to use your code when the property is set.  Instead of during load.  That should also work for you at run time.

I would create a method like this:

```
private void UpdateViewType()
{
 if (this._viewType == ViewType.Month)
                    panelKalendar.Top = yPoloha;
                else if (this._viewType == ViewType.Week)
                    panelKalendar.Top = yPoloha + VYSKA_BUNKY; 
}
```

and then in the property when the value is set call it

```
... 
 set
   {
     _viewType = value;
     UpdateViewType()
     if (panelKalendar != null)
         panelKalendar.Invalidate();
   }
```